# I'm getting an error that I am missing the teminator but I don;t see where it is erroring?"

Tags: powershell

I don't know where my error is in my powershell script.

```
#Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
#Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100

$DATA=IMPORT-CSV "C:\Users\pzd74f\Desktop\SLAPERFMAT2011.csv" -header("SLA1 Applications Availability")"

FOREACH ($LINE in $DATA)
{

$SLADefinition="`'"+$SLADefinition+"`'"


# insert into this

$SQLHEADER=”INSERT INTO [SP2010_EDCSLA_AppDBHIM].[dbo].SLAPerfMatrix ([SLADefinition])"
#insert into this
 $SQLVALUES=" VALUES ($SLADefinition)"


$SQLQUERY=$SQLHEADER+$SQLVALUES

Invoke-Sqlcmd –Query $SQLQuery -ServerInstance localhost
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your code and your question. Right now, it is hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$DATA=IMPORT-CSV "C:\Users\pzd74f\Desktop\SLAPERFMAT2011.csv" -header("SLA1 Applications Availability")"
```

is syntactically incorrect

Remove extra `"` at the end.